# How can an object move at constant velocity in 2 different instances, but in both instances the work done is the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Here's a bit more clarification. If I pick up an object at a constant velocity across distance h it takes me t seconds. If I pick up the same object at a constant velocity through distance h it takes me 2t seconds. According to my textbook in both cases the work done is the same, but how is this possible? Shouldn't the second instance have a force smaller than the first and thus less work?

Comment: Are there other forces involved besides the force you apply and gravity? If not, then this is an impossible situation. There is only one force value that will let you lift the object at a constant velocity if only the weight is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the formulation is not perfect as constant velocity means that the sum of the forces vanishes.

And that velocity could be related to thewe force used to reach it starting from rest, but you can have constant velocity without forces.

Besides this, in the simplest case where  you have two opposite constant forces $\vec{F}_1=-\vec{F}_2$, the work of $\vec{F}_1$ is (assuming $\vec{v}=v \vec{u}_x)$:
$$
W_1 = \int_0^t \vec{F}_1\cdot\vec{v}\,dt
= \vec{F}_1\cdot \vec{u}_x \Big( \int_0^t v\,dt \Big)
$$
and the parenthesis is simply the distance $h$, independent of the time taken to do across it.

In other words  : if you go 2 times faster, the instantaneous power is increased by a factor 2, but as the duration is reduced by the same factor 2, the total work remains unchanged.

Notice that the case on constant velocity case is special, and could accommodate the case of varying forces, but this is not the pitch of your question.

Answer (score 0):

As the body is moving at constant speed which means all forces are balanced. It means the force is same which equal to 'Mg'.